# Youtube videos are coming over footer in the chrome but working fine in Mozilla

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, youtube

I have a site inspire.mobi showing videos from youtube & vimeo. The problem is for youtube videos as these are coming over the footer in chrome but it is working fine in chrome.
Please help on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `<embed>` tag, add `wmode="transparent"`. This will stop the flash object sitting above HTML elements.

If this does not work, then also add `param value="transparent"` to the embedded `<object>`.

Comment: But still the same problem is coming in iphone.

Comment: I'm not sure about iPhones. They don't use flash so it will be a different issue. I think it would be best for you to open a new question for it.